# Calculated Member - Number of Expense lines with a particular status

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, mdx, microsoft-dynamics, cube

i'm quite new to mdx queries in visual studio.

The cube is an out of the box cube (Expense Claims) provided with Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012. The Cube was deployed and opened with VS.

I am trying to count the number of expense lines which have a certain status.

The following is the code i came up with to create a calculated member:

```
CALCULATE;        
CREATE MEMBER MEASURES.[Draft Expenses] AS
SELECT
COUNT(
    NONEMPTY(
                [Expense lines].[Expense lines].MEMBERS,
                [Expense lines].[Document status] == [Expense lines].[Document status].&[1]
            )
) on 0
FROM [Expense management cube]
```

The following error crops up:

> An mdx expression was expected while a full statement was specified.
>   one or more errors were encountered in the MDX script

I tried to use this [link](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2010/10/08/counting-new-and-returning-customers-in-mdx/) as an example but with no success.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: You could just delete this bit `[Expense lines].[Document status] == `. I don't think `==` is a valid `mdx` operator. If you ever need to use equality as a condition then replace `==` with `IS`, although in the context of NonEmpty neither of these operators is apt.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below definition:

```
CREATE MEMBER MEASURES.[Draft Expenses] AS
COUNT
    (
     NonEmpty
            (
             [Expense lines].[Expense lines].MEMBERS,
             {[Expense lines].[Document status].&[1]} * Measures.[SomeOtherMeasure]
            )
    )
```

Comment: what should the other measure be? I'm trying to filter all members according to the status so why would i need to perform that multiplication?

Comment: It could be any measure. And secondly its not multiplication but cross-join.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I tried to do the following:

CALCULATE;        
CREATE MEMBER MEASURES.[Draft Expenses] AS
COUNT
    (
     NonEmpty
            (
             [Expense Lines].[Expense Lines].MEMBERS,
             {[Expense Lines].[Document status].&[1]} * [Measures].[Expense amount]
            )
    )

but it is still showing the same error. any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea why you would put in the `CALCULATE`. Can you remove that and try once?

Comment: For the condition of your NonEmpty function is this a bit more conventional? ... `{([Expense lines].[Document status].&[1], [Measures].[SomeOtherMeasure])}`

Comment: Ya more or less same.

Comment: Code: 
Code:
CREATE MEMBER MEASURES.[Draft Expenses] AS
COUNT
    (
     NonEmpty
            (
             [Expense lines].[Expense lines].MEMBERS,
             {[Expense lines].[Document status].&[1]} * [Measures].[Expense lines Count]
            )
    );

FOllowing error comes up -> The syntax for ',' is incorrect. Im assuming it needs a cross join in the second set?

Comment: There **IS** a cross join in the second set. Are you sure you are typing this in the correct place? Cube-->Calculation-->Script View?

Comment: Update: COUNT
    (
     NonEmpty
            (
             [Expense Report1].[Expense Report1].MEMBERS,
             {[Expense Report1].[Document Status].&[1]} * [Measures].[Expense report Count]
            )
    )

is syntatically correct, but is not returning the right amount. when i go to browser, and dragg and drop the Measures.Expense Lines Count and the Expense Lines.Document Status, the results are different. i check in sql and the ones in the browser table is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sourav's suggestion you could simplify slightly:

```
CREATE MEMBER MEASURES.[Draft Expenses] AS
COUNT(
     NONEMPTY(
         [Expense lines].[Expense lines].MEMBERS,
         {[Expense lines].[Document status].&[1]}
      )
 );
```

Comment: This will throw the "circular reference" error. Try it out :)

Comment: interesting - is this because `MEASURES.[Draft Expenses]` is added to the default member of the hierarchy `MEASURES` but the condition `{[Expense lines].[Document status].&[1]}` is also using the default member? Or is it because nonempty expects its condition to be from a different dimension from its first argument?

Comment: When you don't explicitly include "a different measure", the effect is similar to including every measure in the tuple. So, being a calculated "measure", this leads to self-referencing. If you remember, some time back, we were mulling why possibly you can't have an aggregated measure in measures dimension. I believe the reason is same.

Comment: "similar to including every measure" - I'm not too sure about this. If we do a simple query with a date on rows and a product on columns, with no measure specified then the default measure is included isn't it. Would this not be a similar scenario?

Comment: I take it back. In absence of a measure specified explicitly, the measure in scope is considered, i.e. the measure that got built.

Comment: There is a problem with the syntact:

The syntax for ',' is incorrect.

Im assuming it needs a cross join in the second set?

Comment: @user2415416 Sourav says there will be a circular reference error. I've not tested as I only use `mdx` for querying and I do not play around with `cube-scripts` so my attempt involved some guess-work but thought it'd be interesting to leave it un-deleted.